# How to draw an array in reverse

Tags: java

```
 @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics theGraphics) {
        super.paintComponent(theGraphics);
        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) theGraphics;
        final int height = getHeight();
        final int width = getWidth();
        final int modX = width * PIECE_SIZE;
        final int modY = width * PIECE_SIZE;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                             RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Get points for pieces
        /*if (myGameStatus) {
            for (int y = myBlockList.size() - 1; y > 0; y--) {    
                for (int x = myBlockList.get(y).length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
                    g2d.setColor(getRandomColor());
                    if (myBlockList.get(y)[x] != null) {
                        g2d.drawRect(x * PIECE_SIZE, y * PIECE_SIZE, PIECE_SIZE, PIECE_SIZE);
                        g2d.fillRect(x * PIECE_SIZE, y * PIECE_SIZE, PIECE_SIZE, PIECE_SIZE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }*/
        if (myGameStatus) {
            for (int y = 0; y < myBlockList.size(); y++) {    
                for (int x = 0; x < myBlockList.get(y).length; x++) {
                    g2d.setColor(getRandomColor());
                    if (myBlockList.get(y)[x] != null) {
                        g2d.drawRect(x * PIECE_SIZE, y * PIECE_SIZE, PIECE_SIZE, PIECE_SIZE);
                        g2d.fillRect(x * PIECE_SIZE, y * PIECE_SIZE, PIECE_SIZE, PIECE_SIZE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So I am recieving an ArrayList which is mimicing Tetris on the back end but upside down, therefore the block are moving up and not down. How would I draw this upside down so that the pieces are falling down and not up? As you can see in my code I have tried a reverse loop and a regular loop, both are producing the same bottom to top style of falling.

[Demo](https://i.imgur.com/kKfsmbW.gifv)

Comment: Normalize the point data, subtract normalized point data from one, multiply by the height of the area that will hold the pieces, add the buffer from the top of the screen

Comment: What do you mean by "Normalize the point data"? if you don't mind

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't look like it has anything to do with moving the blocks.  It only draws them on the screen.  Your two versions of the loop change the order in which the blocks are drawn, but the locations of the blocks seems to be implicit in where they appear within the display list.  Your example doesn't show the code that puts the blocks into the list.

Comment: To normalize the points, find the max y value and divide all y values by max so your y values will range from 0-1.  You then inverse the y values by subtracting each of them from 1.  This will invert the direction in which they "fall".  Then multiply each of the y values by height of the area that pieces can move in

Comment: Ok, so I am recieving the ArrayList<Block[]> from an Observable backend class, the array list contains the tetris board with the appropriate pieces in their spots, including as they move the arraylist fills up with the blocks. So what I am doing is iterating over the arraylist, seeing which blocks are filled and then trying to draw those blocks. Unfortunately the arraylist is in reverse y order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g2d.drawRect is responsible for the where placement. `y * PIECE_SIZE` specifically for the y position. You need to inverse the y position with `MAX_y_value - (y * PIECE_SIZE)`

Comment: Max y value being what exactly? the height of my grid?

Comment: @Jacob Yes. Though depending on where y = 0 is, you may have to adjust the +/-.

Comment: Thank you man. this worked. final int tempY = (height - 28) - (y * PIECE_SIZE);

Answer (score 1):

The order you draw the pieces matters only for how the pieces overlap on screen. In this case they don't. So that order doesn't matter. What matters is how you are declaring the data in your other code and when you change the position, you need to add Y to them rather than subtract Y. Basically all computer graphics are +Y -> Down.

Show the code where you iterate the position and it would be trivial to tell you to change that - into a +.

Comment: Ya I am not allowed to change the backend code, therefore I cant reverse it, I wish I could